# Why is my detail lain lain Data Field Can't Be Stored and Displayed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, validation

I make checkbox that when the user checked lain-lain it will popping a form again for give the detail desc [The Checkbox Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW2QU.png)
but when the user give another desc for the detail lain lain form, the data cant be stored and displayed on my detail or index.

here is my code for the form

```
<div class="row mb-3">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <label for="pembayaran" class="col-form-label">Pembayaran</label>
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="booking"
                                            name="pembayaran[]" value="Booking">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="booking">Booking</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="dp"
                                            name="pembayaran[]" value="DP">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="dp">DP</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="cbth"
                                            name="pembayaran[]" value="CBTH">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="cbth">CBTH</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="angsuran"
                                            name="pembayaran[]" value="Angsuran">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="angsuran">Angsuran ke</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="ket"
                                            name="pembayaran[]" value="KET">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="ket">KET</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="lainlain"
                                            name="pembayaran[]" value="Lain-lain">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="lainlain">Lain-lain</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="lainlain-form" style="display: none;">
                                <div class="row mb-3">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <label for="lainlaininput" class="col-form-label">Detail Lain-lain</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lainlaininput"
                                            name="lainlaininput" placeholder="Masukkan detail lain-lain">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <script>
                                // Dapatkan semua elemen checkbox
                                var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

                                // Tambahkan event listener untuk setiap checkbox
                                checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
                                    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
                                        // Jika checkbox yang sedang diubah adalah checkbox yang telah dicentang, nonaktifkan yang lainnya
                                        if (this.checked) {
                                            checkboxes.forEach(function(otherCheckbox) {
                                                if (otherCheckbox !== checkbox) {
                                                    otherCheckbox.disabled = true;
                                                }
                                            });
                                        } else {
                                            // Jika checkbox yang sedang diubah tidak dicentang, aktifkan yang lainnya
                                            checkboxes.forEach(function(otherCheckbox) {
                                                otherCheckbox.disabled = false;
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
                                });
                            </script>
                            <script>
                                // Dapatkan elemen checkbox "Lain-lain"
                                var lainlainCheckbox = document.getElementById('lainlain');

                                // Dapatkan elemen form tambahan
                                var lainlainForm = document.getElementById('lainlain-form');

                                // Tambahkan event listener ke checkbox "Lain-lain"
                                lainlainCheckbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
                                    // Jika checkbox "Lain-lain" dicentang, tampilkan form tambahan
                                    if (this.checked) {
                                        lainlainForm.style.display = 'block';
                                    } else {
                                        // Jika checkbox "Lain-lain" tidak dicentang, sembunyikan form tambahan
                                        lainlainForm.style.display = 'none';
                                    }
                                });
                            </script>
```

and this is my controller code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Exports\ExportKwitansi;
use App\Models\Kwitansi;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

class KwitansiController extends Controller
{
    protected $kwitansis;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->kwitansis = Kwitansi::all();
    }

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->has('search')) {
            $kwitansis = Kwitansi::where('nomor_kwitansi', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')
                ->orWhere('nama_lengkap', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')
                ->get();

            if ($kwitansis->count() == 0) {
                session()->flash('error', 'Kwitansi tidak ditemukan');

                return redirect('/kwitansi');
            }
        } else {
            $kwitansis = Kwitansi::all();
        }

        return view('kwitansi.index', [
            'kwitansis' => $kwitansis,
        ]);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $lastSerialNumber = Kwitansi::latest('nomor_kwitansi')->first();

        if ($lastSerialNumber) {
            $lastNumber = (int) substr($lastSerialNumber->nomor_kwitansi, 4);
            $nextNumber = $lastNumber + 1;
        } else {
            $nextNumber = 1;
        }

        $serialNumber = 'SMS-' . str_pad($nextNumber, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

        return view('kwitansi.create', compact('serialNumber'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $lastSerialNumber = Kwitansi::latest('nomor_kwitansi')->first();

            if ($lastSerialNumber) {
                $lastNumber = (int) substr($lastSerialNumber->nomor_kwitansi, 4);
                $nextNumber = $lastNumber + 1;
            } else {
                $nextNumber = 1;
            }

            $serialNumber = 'SMS-' . str_pad($nextNumber, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

            $validatedData = $request->validate([
                'nama_lengkap' => 'required',
                'alamat' => 'required',
                'no_hp' => 'required',
                'terbilang' => 'required',
                'lokasi' => 'required',
                'no_kavling' => 'required',
                'type' => 'required',
                'jumlah' => 'required',
            ]);

            // Mengubah pilihan checkbox menjadi string yang dipisahkan oleh koma
            $pembayaran = implode(', ', $request->input('pembayaran'));

            // Memeriksa apakah checkbox "Lain-lain" dicentang
            // Periksa apakah kotak centang "Lain-lain" dicentang
            if ($request->has('lainlain')) {
                // Ambil data input "Lain-lain" dan tambahkan ke dalam kolom "pembayaran"
                $lainlaininput = $request->input('lainlaininput');
                $pembayaran .= ', ' . $lainlaininput;
            }
            
            $validatedData['nomor_kwitansi'] = $serialNumber;
            $validatedData['pembayaran'] = $pembayaran; // Menyimpan pilihan checkbox ke dalam kolom 'pembayaran'
            
            Kwitansi::create($validatedData);
            
            return redirect('/kwitansi');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            session()->flash('error', $e->getMessage());

            return back();
        }
    }

    public function detail($id)
    {
        $kwitansi = $this->kwitansis->find($id);

        if (!$kwitansi) {
            session()->flash('error', 'Kwitansi tidak ditemukan');

            return redirect('/kwitansi');
        }

        return view('kwitansi.detail', compact('kwitansi'));
    }
    public function print($id)
    {
        $kwitansi = $this->kwitansis->find($id);

        if (!$kwitansi) {
            session()->flash('error', 'Kwitansi tidak ditemukan');

            return redirect('/kwitansi');
        }

        return view('kwitansi.cetak', compact('kwitansi'));
    }

    public function edit(Kwitansi $kwitansi)
    {
        return view('kwitansi.edit', compact('kwitansi'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Kwitansi $kwitansi)
    {
        // dd($request->all());
        try {
            $rules = [
                'nama_lengkap' => 'required',
                'alamat' => 'required',
                'no_hp' => 'required',
                'terbilang' => 'required',
                'lokasi' => 'required',
                'no_kavling' => 'required',
                'type' => 'required',
                'jumlah' => 'required',
            ];

            $validatedData = $request->validate($rules);

            // Mengubah pilihan checkbox menjadi string yang dipisahkan oleh koma
            $pembayaran = implode(', ', $request->input('pembayaran'));

            // Memeriksa apakah checkbox "Lain-lain" dicentang
            if ($request->has('lainlain')) {
                // Ambil data input "Lain-lain" dan tambahkan ke dalam kolom "pembayaran"
                $lainlaininput = $request->input('lainlaininput');
                $pembayaran .= ', ' . $lainlaininput;
            }

            $validatedData['pembayaran'] = $pembayaran; // Menyimpan pilihan checkbox ke dalam kolom 'pembayaran'

            // Update data kwitansi
            $kwitansi->update($validatedData);

            return redirect('/kwitansi')->with('success', 'Kwitansi berhasil diperbarui');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            session()->flash('error', $e->getMessage());

            return back();
        }
    }

    public function destroy(Kwitansi $kwitansi)
    {
        Kwitansi::destroy($kwitansi->id);

        return redirect('/kwitansi');
    }

    function export_excel()
    {
        return Excel::Download(new ExportKwitansi(), 'Kwitansi.xlsx');
    }
}
```

and this is my table view code

```
<table class="table table-hover text-center" id="kwitansi-table">
            <thead>
                <tr class="bg-info">
                    <th style="width: 2rem; justify-content: center; align-items: center; cursor: pointer;"
                        id="sortNo">No.</th>
                    <th style="width: 4.5rem; cursor: pointer;" id="sortKwitansi">No. Kwitansi</th>
                    <th style="width: 6rem; cursor: pointer;" id="sortNama">Nama Lengkap</th>
                    <th style="width: 10rem;">Alamat</th>
                    <th style="width: 4.5rem;">No. HP</th>
                    <th style="width: 8.5rem;">Terbilang</th>
                    <th style="width: 4rem;">Pembayaran</th>
                    <th style="width: 4rem;">Nama Perumahan</th>
                    <th style="width: 1rem;">No. Kavling</th>
                    <th style="width: 1rem;">Type</th>
                    <th style="width: 5rem;">Jumlah</th>
                    <th style="width: 6.7rem;">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($kwitansis as $kwitansi)
                    <tr onclick="window.location.href='{{ route('kwitansi.detail', $kwitansi->id) }}';"
                        style="cursor: pointer;">
                        <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $kwitansi->nomor_kwitansi }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $kwitansi->nama_lengkap }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $kwitansi->alamat }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $kwitansi->no_hp }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $kwitansi->terbilang }}</td>
                        <td>
                            @if (in_array('Lain-lain', explode(', ', $kwitansi->pembayaran)))
                                {{ $kwitansi->lainlaininput }}
                            @else
                                {{ $kwitansi->pembayaran }}
                            @endif
                        </td>
                        <td>{{ $kwitansi->lokasi }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $kwitansi->no_kavling }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $kwitansi->type }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $kwitansi->jumlah }}</td>
                        <td
                            style="padding-left: 1rem; display: flex; height: 6rem; justify-content: space-around; align-items: center">
                            <button class="btn btn-warning"
                                style="margin:0 ; padding: 6.5px 8px 6.5px 8px; border-radius: 100%;">
                                <a href="{{ route('kwitansi.edit', $kwitansi->id) }}">
                                    <img src="{{ asset('icon/pen2.svg') }}" alt=""
                                        style="width: 26px; height: 26px">
                                </a>
                            </button>
                            <form action="{{ route('kwitansi.destroy', $kwitansi->id) }}}}" method="POST"
                                class="d-inline-grid">
                                @method('delete')
                                @csrf
                                <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"
                                    style="margin:0 ; padding: 6.5px 8px 6.5px 8px; border-radius: 100%;">
                                    <img src="{{ asset('icon/trash3.svg') }}" alt="">
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

do I need to add lainlaininput to my Database Table?
[My Database Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqUz8.png)
[Debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZ7oI.png)

I expect  the when the user fill Detail lain lain input [detail lain lain filled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rz7ir.png) it will stored and get displayed too on my table, and it could be editable too

Comment: According to your second image, you have a lainlaininput field in your table. Is that only an illustration, or do you actually have that field? If it exists, does it have some values that you attempted to insert earlier? Do you get some errors when you attempt to insert a record with a lain-lain detail?

Comment: @LajosArpad It originally doesn't have lainlaininput field on the table, its just an illustration bcs I got confused do I need to add lainlaininput field on nah on my table

Answer (score 1):

You will need to store that field somehow. You could create a field for this detail if you would like, but given the fact that this is an optional field, you might want to create a table for lain-lain with a foreign key to your kwitansis table and with a detail field.

In that case you will be able to fill the description field by either left-joining your lain-lain table to your kwitansis, or reading it separately by foreign key, depending on which fits your scenario the best. This code chunk

```
$pembayaran .= ', ' . $lainlaininput;
```

does not look good. First, you are taking a user input without validating it and store it straightly into `$validatedData`, secondly, you append this to the values, whereas the field does not exist and it's likely not specified either.

You will need to refactor your code and I would advise you to focus with a keen eye on security as well. But, to avoid drifting from our topic: I would create a lainlain table with a foreign key to your kwitansis table and when the form is submitted with a lainlain field being passed, then just insert a new record into this lainlain table, specifying which kwitansis it belongs to and what its description is.